# Estimating parameters of the bivariate distribution of parameters of Beta-distribution

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, beta-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

Suppose, I observe $n$ draws from $n$ Beta-distibutions (one from each), and each of them has unknown parameters $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$. However, it is known that all $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are drawn from the same bivariate distribution (say, truncated normal with parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$). Is it possible to directly estimate $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ using MLE or any other methods?

What if instead I observe multiple draws from each of the Beta-distributions?